# Grep for This and NOT That in a File?

Tags: macos, bash, grep

How can I grep for files in a directory structure that have this text

```
addDesignControlChangeNotification
```

but are missing this text

```
removeDesignControlChangeNotification
```

Thanks!

**Note:** I mean the directory the script starts in and all subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm, in the main dir, or main dir and subdirectories?

Comment: I mean the dir we start the script in and all subdirectories. Sorry that wasn't clear before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that is loosely based on Rich Homolka's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/577512/151431), but works on directory trees:

```
find . -type f  -exec grep -l addDesignControlChangeNotification {} \; | 
 while IFS= read -r file; do 
   grep -q removeDesignControlChangeNotification "$file" > /dev/null ; 
   [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo $file; 
 done
```

Any files returned will contain `addDesignControlChangeNotification` but not `removeDesignControlChangeNotification`.

EXPLANATION:

- `find . -type f  -exec grep -l foo {} \;`: This will print all files in any subdirectory of the current directory that contain the string `foo`. The `-l` flag causes grep to only print the names of matching files.
- `while read file` :  this iterates through each file found above, saving its name in the variable `$file`.
- `grep -q bar "$file" > /dev/null` : this comand loks for the string `bar` in each of the files that contained `foo`.
- `[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo $file;` : If the return value (`$?`) of the `grep` command was 0 (i.e. if the string was not in the file), print the name of the file.

Comment: Awesome, I'm using `find . -name '*.m' -type f  -exec grep -l addDesignControlChangeNotification {}...`  which I added myself since I didn't mention it in the question ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
FIRST=addDesignControlChangeNotification
SECOND=removeDesignControlChangeNotification
grep -l $FIRST * | while IFS= read -r FILE
do
    grep $SECOND "$FILE" &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "File $FILE has $FIRST but not $SECOND"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Looks great, but I'm getting "Is a directory" instead of actually entering into those directories. Any idea what's wrong? Thank you +1!

Comment: @Yar, you can add an `-r` to the first `grep` command if you want to recurse directories. Or you can use my answer ;).

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
comm -2 -3 <(grep -rl addDesignControlChangeNotification     . | sort ) \
           <(grep -rl removeDesignControlChangeNotification  . | sort )
```

`grep -r` is a recursive grep, `<()` is *process substitution*, and `comm` shows you lines that a pair of (sorted) files do/don't have in common. In this case we only want the column 1 output: lines in the first file (where "file" is really grep output) which are not in the second.